# Cloudify - Openstack-Plugin - How to grant permissions to write/read key to the path specified into KeyPair Cloudify building block

Tags: openstack, cloudify

when i try to deploy a blueprint with a keypair block, Cloudify returns the subsequent error:

Task failed 'nova_plugin.keypair.create' -> [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/root/key.key'

Where '/root/key.key' is the full path where i want the private key will be written on Cloudify manager machine.

I think that the issue is generated becouse of Cloudify itself does'nt knows access credentials of the cloudify manager machine. So I ask you how can I specify them to be used by Cloudify to write correctly the key in specified path.

Regards. Luca Longo

Answer (score 0):

The user cloudify is using doesn't have permissions to write to /root.
We usually put our key pairs in /etc/cloudify.

Answer (score 0):

All manager-side plugin operations in Cloudify, are run as the user `cfyuser`.

You are getting this error because the user `cfyuser` doesn't have permissions to write into `/root`.

`cfyuser` is created with `/etc/cloudify` as its home directory, and by default, it has access to write to it.